# Installing Qt5 on ubuntu 13.04 using .run file

Tags: bash, qt, ubuntu

I downloaded the official  `.run`  file for installing Qt5 on ubuntu 64bit. I have given the file, execution permission but when I try running it with:

```
$sh ./qt.run
```

I get the folowing errors:

```
./qt.run: 1: ./qt.run: ELF: not found
./qt.run: 1: ./qt.run: @8: not found
./qt.run: 10: ./qt.run: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

and by running it like this:

```
./qt.run
```

I get:

```
No marker found, stopped after 1.00 MiB.
```

I have ubuntu 13.04 64bit, help please...

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are running 64 bit executable on 64 bit system? What is the output of the following commands: `uname -a` and `file qt.run`?

Comment: `uname -a` produces:`Linux reza-laptop 3.8.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 14 22:16:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `file qt.run` produces: `qt.run: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x23e55b22a0b76372aab6be2da0272d0140ba78b1, not stripped`

Comment: And have you tried: `chmod +x qt.run` and `./qt.run` (I mean without `sh`)?

Comment: yes, same results... the permission is 755...

Comment: I mean same as the things I have written in my question.

Comment: If you post here the link to the exact Qt5 download file, I will try to reproduce your problem once I get back to my ubuntu machine. For know I have no clue :/

Comment: [this](http://qt-project.org/downloads) is the main download page, and [this](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86_64-offline.run) is the file I have Downloaded... thanks a lot for your time... :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error you're getting, but on my Ubuntu (13.04, 64 bit, same as yours) I get no error whatsoever. So the only idea I got is to update your system and, if that doesn't help, reinstall.

Comment: tnx... I installed it using ubuntu software center...